# Make - Dependency building different than explicit build

Tags: makefile, game-boy-advance

I have a rule in my makefile:

```
$(OW_GROUP_ONE_C): $(OW_GROUP_ONE_PNG)
for file in $^; \
do \`enter code here`
        grit $$file -ftc -fh\! -fa -gt -gz\! -gB4 -m\! -p -pzl -pu16 -o $@; \
done
```

It builds a single c file out of different images, those are iterated in a for loop (They are, I checked using an echo)

The rule which depends on that is

```
$(OW_GROUP_ONE_O): $(OW_GROUP_ONE_C)
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```

which is executed via

```
$(SPRITES_BINARY): $(NORMAL_PAL_OBJ) $(SHINY_PAL_OBJ) $(SPRITE_FRONT_OBJ) $(SPRITE_BACK_OBJ) $(NORMAL_CASTFORM_PAL_OBJ) $(SHINY_CASTFORM_PAL_OBJ) $(CASTFORM_FRONT_OBJ) $(CASTFORM_BACK_OBJ) $(OW_GROUP_ONE_O)
```

If I execute the rule by calling "make $(OW_GROUP_ONE_C)" everything works fine, but as soon as the rule is executed via dependency from another rule, the loop seems to just read the first file. I again used echo to check, but the loop accumulates all files in the list. I don't know what the deal i, the tool (GRIT - GBA raster image transmogrifier) should be able to handle that, but there must be a difference between calling the rule explicit if it works that way...

Thanks in advance for any hints!

Comment: [mcve] that replicates the issue please.

Comment: I added the neccessary dependent rules, thats all there is. Even if I call make $(OW_GROUP_ONE_O) it builds just fine, but as soon as I call make $(SPRITES_BINARY) it replicates said problems...

Comment: If you won't give us a minimal complete example, how about an experiment: write a new rule with only half of the the prerequisites of `$(SPRITES_BINARY)` (including `$(OW_GROUP_ONE_O)`), try to execute it, and tell us whether the loop works.